# Incompatible argument type conversion using macro

Tags: c, debugging, type-conversion

I am trying to use a single macro argument (provided by third party) to display a string with placeholders and values of those place holder.

```
#define DBG1(AR1)    do{             \
                        printf(AR1); \
                     }while(0);

int main()
{
  int varDummy = 123;

  /* Expecting Test Message 123*/
  DBG1(("Test Message %d\r\n", varDummy));

  return 0;
}
```

Notice the argument of **DBG1** *("Test Message %d\r\n", varDummy)* is in parentheses and is being treated whole as a string i.e. const char* and error shows up that varDummy not allowed to be converted due to it's int type.

In the actual code the argument of DBG1 has different number of place holders (%d, %x...) and respective values which have to be printed. Apparently I am unable to display the passed string along with its place holder values.

In the real code I have the following macro from third party

```
LWIP_DEBUGF(SOCKETS_DEBUG, ("lwip_recvfrom(%d, %p, %"SZT_F", 0x%x, ..)\n", s, mem, len, flags));

/* discarding the first argument */
#define LWIP_DEBUGF(debug, message) do{                 \
                                        DBG1(message)   \
                                     }while(0);
```

Please note this is a resource constrained embedded system.

Comment: semicolon at the end of your macro is a big no-no

Comment: either create a vararg function or simply do `#define DBG1 printf`. Then remove the double parentheses. Can you do that? or there are constraints that we don't know?

Comment: please [edit] your question. It's unreadable in comments.

Comment: @EmbeddedEngr - _In the real code_ the call of `LWIP_DEBUGF` doesn't go before the macro definition, does it? If the shown order is wrong, you should correct that.

Comment: @Armali it goes to another macro. Please refer https://github.com/yarrick/lwip/blob/1a10a942f22c5d139573c5a4b68431a57ea47d30/src/include/lwip/debug.h#L145

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Notice the argument of **DBG1** *("Test Message %d\r\n", varDummy)* is in parentheses …

This problem is at the same time the solution. Since there are already parentheses, you need not supply them in your `DBG1` macro and can change `printf(AR1); \` to `printf AR1; \`. Besides that, you can simplify the macro to

```
#define DBG1(AR1)   printf AR1;
```

(since you can't change the `LWIP_DEBUGF` *macro from third party*, we unfortunately have to keep the semicolon).

Comment: I really wouldn't advise anyone, including my worst enemies, to write macros that assume that the parameter is passed inside a parenthesis. Please don't invite your own private, secret macro languages.

Comment: @Armali Thank you. It makes sense. MACRO EXPANSION literally would have made it clear `printf(("Test Message %d\r\n",varDummy ));` The problem is now clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary buffer to hold the adjointed string, something like this:

```
#define DBG1(AR1) do{\
                  printf(AR1);\
                  } while(0)
#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

int main()
{
    int varDummy = 123;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    sprintf(buffer, "Test Message %d\r\n", varDummy);
    /* Expecting Test Message 123*/
    DBG1(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using sprintf on a resource-constrained embedded system is even worse than using printf.

Answer (score 0):

> Notice the argument of DBG1 is in parentheses

Yeah that's the problem, you are calling `printf(("Test Message %d\r\n", varDummy));` where the inner parentheses has turned the `,` from a function argument separator into the comma operator. The comma operator discards the left operand and returns the right. Which is `int`, a type incompatible with the format string of `printf`, which explains the compiler error.

Instead you should be using a variadic macro:

```
#define DBG1(AR1,...) printf(AR1, __VA_ARGS__)
...
DBG1("Test Message %d\r\n", varDummy);
```

The do-while(0) trick is pointless to use in this case.

---

> Please note this is a resource constrained embedded system.

Then you shouldn't be using stdio.h or variadic functions in the first place. Instead, design your own product-specific logging module. Writing a little snippet that spits out strings on UART isn't rocket science.

Similarly, parsing raw binary data from UART isn't rocket science either, so you don't actually need the string conversion, just a decent terminal program on the PC.

Comment: I don't want to go inside more details and complicate it. I have no problem playing with byte stream and directing to the appropriate UART instance. I have to use a custom log function which is managed by the library and only prints out when it should (it takes care of radio stack timing requirements)